# Solving ns3 packet receiption issue

Tags: c++

I am using ns3 to send a message and its hash using client-server echo application, i have created two packets to do so , one for the message and the other for the hash ,
  at sever i store the packet received content in a string variable "called it str" 
when I received them got the message first with its correct size 
but when I receive later the hash i got correct packet size but not when i stroe it my str

At time 2s client sent Message of  14 AND bytes With Hash of 64 bytes to 10.1.1.2 port 9
At time 2.00207s server received 14 AND str  14 bytes from 10.1.1.1 port 49153

At time 2.00222s server received 64 AND str  65 bytes from 10.1.1.1 port 49153

Ptr packet;
  Address from;

```
       while ((packet = socket->RecvFrom (from))) 

      { 


    uint8_t *buffer = new uint8_t[packet->GetSize ()];

    packet->CopyData(buffer, packet->GetSize ());
   std::string str = (char*)buffer;
```

Comment: I think you may not find an answer here about NS-3. Last year I did my research using the NS-2 simulator, and finding help was very frustrating. I'm not sure about NS-3, but there is a website for NS-2 which it didn't help me that much. Anyways, you better dig yourself. By the way, you tagged C++, but NS-3 is not C++.

Comment: I tagged C++ because NS3 scripts and codes are written in C++

Comment: I guess I've found the solution, I read about Null Terminating string problem and adding (+1) for the packet size can solve it .